# Find keys with wildcard on S3

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I have a list of UUID's for files I need to purge but the files all start with a UNIX timestamp which I want to ignore. How do I list these files? This what I have so far but obviously s3 does not accept wildcards.

```php
$files = $s3->listObjectsV2([
    'Bucket' => 'logs',
    'MaxKeys' => 5,
    'Prefix' => "docker/*{$uuid}",
    ]);
```

Comment: You'll need to set the Prefix to only `docker/` and filter the list of values after the return from S3.

Comment: I was hoping there was an AWS side command because there are a lot of files to go through.

Comment: Just to clarify, Do you want to list all the files having a specific UUID and also want to ignore the files which are having UNIX timestamps in their names?

Comment: have a UUID in the names. The timestamp is the reason I cannot just do `docker/{$uuid}`

Comment: You can use `ListObjects()` with a given **Prefix** only. Amazon S3 does not support listing via _suffix_ or _regex_.

Comment: Aye, that is what I was afraid of. I thought maybe the internet would have something I did not know about.

Comment: S3 is not a filesystem, it's a key-value store. Just like any or KV store if you don't know the exact name of the key you want, you're going to have to list all the keys and do the search yourself. Be aware that there are limits to how many entries can be returned by a single API call, and fees for API calls. Listing a bucket or prefix with millions of keys may cost tens of dollars. If you want a more FS-like experience you'll need to build/maintain your own index of the contents, otherwise I'd recommend being more fastidious in cleaning up old files at a time when you know the exact key name.